# Common dependency lib version with yarn workspaces

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

Assuming I have an external NPM lib dependency that is shared among different workspaces, is it possible to set a single version for all dependant workspaces? What if this dependency is a peer or dependency ?

e.g

```
// external-lib-dep in npm

//package1's package.json
...
"dependencies": {
   "external-lib-dep": "^1.0.0"
}
...

// package2's package.json
...
"dependencies": {
   "external-lib-dep": "^1.2.0"
}
...

// package3's package.json
...
"dependencies": {
   "very-different-external-lib-dep": "^1.2.0"
}
...
```

Is it possible to somehow "share" the versions of deps instead of copying it over and over again? (just like `dependencyManagement` in parent pom in maven).

What if the monorepo holds "common" libs for all services in a certain company. Will they solution work when I use one of the libs in my service?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to share the versions of dependency among workspaces in one specific way.

Your workspaces should declare `external-lib-dep` in their `peerDependencies`. And in your monorepo root `package.json` you should declare `external-lib-dep` in `dependencies`. This way your workspaces will "inherit" `external-lib-dep` version from the root workspace.

Comment: Awesome! thnx! what version should I set in the peer dep section ?

Comment: You can set `*` as a version in peer dep section, if you want to pick any version provided by root `package.json`

Comment: What if the monorepo holds all the standard backend libs for the company? 
I think that if I set one of the libs as a dep in a service, I'll get a * peer dependency requirement

Comment: Sorry, I can only base my answer on information that was initially present in your question. Where the information about standard backend libs can be found in your question?